# How to get the productCount to display using Sebwite sidebar?

Tags: magento2, sidebar

I'm trying to display the product Count next to each category and child category. I'm using $category->getProductCount() but nothing is showing up.

Here is my sidebar.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Category sidebar
 *
 * @var $block Sebwite\Sidebar\Block\Sidebar
 */
$isEnabled     = $block->isEnabled();
$titleText     = $block->getTitleText();
$isOpenOnLoad  = $block->isOpenOnLoad();
$categories    = $block->getCategories();

if ($isEnabled && count($categories)>0) {
?>

    <h3><?= $titleText; ?></h3>
    <ul class="o-list">

    <?php
    // Loop through categories
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) :
        ?>
        <li class="level0<?php echo($block->isActive($category) ? ' active' : ''); ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $block->getCategoryUrl($category); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>" class="<?php echo($block->isActive($category) ? ' active' : ''); ?>">
                <?php echo $category->getName(); ?>
                <?php 
                echo $category->getProductCount();?>
            </a>
            <?php if ( $category->hasChildren() ) : ?>
                <span class="expand"><?php echo $block->isActive($category) ? '<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>'; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $block->getChildCategoryView($category); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php if ($isOpenOnLoad) { ?>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'sidebarmodule'], function($) {
            $('.is-active').parents('ul').css('display','block');
            $('.is-active').parents('li').addClass('active');
            $('.is-active').parents('li').find('> span i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
        });
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'sidebarmodule'], function($) {});
    </script>
<?php }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method $category->getProductCollection()->count();

Comment: It gives me a Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on null. I'm not sure what I am missing

Comment: I think ProductCollection() returns the number of categories but not the number of products if I'm not mistaken?